# How to process lazily two strings at once?

Tags: string, scala, stream, lazy-evaluation

Suppose I need a function to filter out characters of `chars` from a string `str` and then take only `k` first characters from the result:

```
def cleanTrim(str: String, chars: Set[Char], k: Int): String =
  str.filterNot(chars).take(k)
```

This implementation is suboptimal since it needlessly scans the whole string. In order to optimize it we can use `view` or event `Stream` to scan the input lazily, e.g:

```
def cleanTrim(str: String, chars: Set[Char], k: Int): String =
  str.view.foldLeft("") { case (r, c) => if (chars.contains(c)) r + c else r }.take(k)
```

Suppose now that I need to clean and trim lazily *two* strings. I would like to `fold` them lazily to process a single character from both of them at once and return both results.

```
def cleanTrim2(str1: String,
               str2: String,
               chars: Set[Char],
               k: Int): (String, String) = ???
```

How would you suggest implement it ?

Comment: You take in two strings, filter them and return a single string? Which one do you return?

Comment: My mistake. I need to return both. Updating the question.

Comment: Why not take a sequence, fold over all of it and return it?

Comment: Why not take a sequence, fold over all of it and return it?

Comment: Where is the `k: Int` being used in your second version of `cleanTrim`? You are saying you want to filter a "single charater from both of them" but you pass a `Set[Char]` as parameter?

Comment: I forgot `take(k)`. Updating the question.

Comment: 1) Why do you use `foldLeft` in the `view` version? You could just do `str.view.filterNot(chars).take(k).force`. 2) What do you mean by folding both at once? Why can't you just use `(cleanTrim(str1), cleanTrim(str2))`?

Comment: (1) thanks, did not think of it (2) well ... I _actually_ need to clean two strings and then take k/2 chars of each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not see any gain of using laziness. In your second implementation of `cleanTrim` you still scan whole string, actually you can't check if string `contains` char without scanning whole string (or stream or view).

UPD: @thwiegan right, I didn't read the question carefully.

UPD2: Ok, my second try, don't know if it is important for you to use `fold`, but I see the way to make it more clear:

```
def cleanTrim2(str1: String, str2: String, chars: Set[Char], k: Int): (String, String) = {
        val result1 = str1.iterator.filterNot(chars).take(k).mkString
        val result2 = str2.iterator.filterNot(chars).take(k).mkString
        (result1, result2)
    }
```

Comment: He only needs a certain number of characters of that string. So if he has a string of length 20 and he only needs 10 (k) then he only has to scan until he has those 10 characters, which are not in the char set. You are right about the second implementation though, but I think he just forgot to put the `take(k)` at the end (which I pointed out in my comment).