# How to clean and trim two strings lazily?

Tags: string, scala, lazy-evaluation

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44699776/how-to-process-lazily-two-strings-at-once).

Suppose I need to remove certain characters from two input strings `s1` and `s2` and then return their substrings `t1` and `t2` as follows:

- `t1` and `t2` are "cleaned"
- `t1` and `t2` have the same length
- `t1` and `t2` length is at most `k`
- `t1` and `t2` are as long as possible

I can write a suboptimal implementation that scans the whole input like this:

```
def cleanTrim(s1: String, s2: String, chars: Set[Char], k: Int): (String, String) = {
  val cleaned1 = s1.filterNot(chars)
  val cleaned2 = s2.filterNot(chars)
  val k1 = math.min(cleaned1.length, k)
  val k2 = math.min(cleaned2.length, k)
  val n = math.min(k1, k2)
  val t1 = cleaned1.substring(0, n)
  val t2 = cleaned2.substring(0, n)
  (t1, t2)
}
```

How would you suggest write it lazily (e.g. with `Stream`) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to process lazily two strings at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44699776/how-to-process-lazily-two-strings-at-once)

Comment: I've given you the answer in you previous question and you didn't approve it or commented it. So I mark this question as duplicate.

Comment: Another user commented your answer. I agree with the comment and have nothing to add.

Comment: @Michel But it has two updates, one of which contains code you looking for.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I will have a look ...

Comment: @mulya I have accepted your answer to my previous question. Thanks a lot. However I think this question is different. Let me think of an example to show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to doing it lazily, is that you can `zip` two filtered streams/iterators/views to both traverse them at once and cut the longer one to have the same size as the shorter.

I've done several implementations of this approach to compare the performance of functional and imperative implementations. Here is the code of the methods:

```
def cleanTrim_Streams(s1: String, s2: String, chars: Set[Char], k: Int): (String, String) = {
  def stream(s: String) = s.toStream.filterNot(chars)
  val (stream1, stream2) = stream(s1).zip(stream(s2)).take(k).unzip
  (stream1.mkString, stream2.mkString)
}

def cleanTrim_IteratorsFold(s1: String, s2: String, chars: Set[Char], k: Int): (String, String) = {
  def iter(s: String) = s.iterator.filterNot(chars)
  iter(s1).zip(iter(s2)).take(k).foldLeft(("", "")) {
    case ((r1, r2), (c1, c2)) => (r1 + c1, r2 + c2)
  }
}

def cleanTrim_Views(s1: String, s2: String, chars: Set[Char], k: Int): (String, String) = {
  def view(s: String) = s.view.filterNot(chars)
  val (v1, v2) = view(s1).zip(view(s2)).take(k).unzip
  (v1.mkString, v2.mkString)
}

def cleanTrim_FullTraverse(s1: String, s2: String, chars: Set[Char], k: Int): (String, String) = {
  val cleaned1 = s1.filterNot(chars)
  val cleaned2 = s2.filterNot(chars)
  val k1 = math.min(cleaned1.length, k)
  val k2 = math.min(cleaned2.length, k)
  val n = math.min(k1, k2)
  val t1 = cleaned1.substring(0, n)
  val t2 = cleaned2.substring(0, n)
  (t1, t2)
}

def cleanTrim_IteratorsImperative(s1: String, s2: String, chars: Set[Char], k: Int): (String, String) = {
  def iter(s: String) = s.iterator.filterNot(chars)

  val b1 = new StringBuilder
  val b2 = new StringBuilder
  for ((c1, c2) <- iter(s1).zip(iter(s2)).take(k)) {
    b1 += c1
    b2 += c2
  }

  (b1.result(), b2.result())
}

def cleanTrim_Imperative(s1: String, s2: String, chars: Set[Char], k: Int): (String, String) = {
  var i1 = 0
  var i2 = 0

  val b1 = new StringBuilder
  val b2 = new StringBuilder

  while (b1.size < k && b2.size < k) {

    while (i1 < s1.length && chars.contains(s1(i1))) i1 += 1
    while (i2 < s2.length && chars.contains(s2(i2))) i2 += 1

    if (i1 >= s1.length || i2 >= s2.length) return (b1.result(), b2.result())

    b1 += s1(i1); i1 += 1
    b2 += s2(i2); i2 += 1
  }

  (b1.result(), b2.result())
}
```

And here are the results from my benchmarks with `s1.size` = 100, `s2.size` = 200, `chars.size` = 3, trimmed size = 86 and `k` = either 50 or 100.

```
[info] Benchmark                       (maxLength)  Mode  Cnt    Score    Error  Units
[info] Benchmarks.fullTraverse                  50  avgt   10    5,591 ±  2,586  us/op
[info] Benchmarks.fullTraverse                 100  avgt   10    5,678 ±  2,799  us/op
[info] Benchmarks.imperative                    50  avgt   10    1,091 ±  0,066  us/op
[info] Benchmarks.imperative                   100  avgt   10    2,384 ±  0,931  us/op
[info] Benchmarks.iteratorsFold                 50  avgt   10    4,164 ±  0,214  us/op
[info] Benchmarks.iteratorsFold                100  avgt   10   11,783 ±  8,251  us/op
[info] Benchmarks.iteratorsImperative           50  avgt   10    4,104 ±  1,241  us/op
[info] Benchmarks.iteratorsImperative          100  avgt   10    9,695 ±  5,554  us/op
[info] Benchmarks.streams                       50  avgt   10   38,670 ±  3,547  us/op
[info] Benchmarks.streams                      100  avgt   10  116,573 ± 72,291  us/op
[info] Benchmarks.views                         50  avgt   10   17,209 ± 30,554  us/op
[info] Benchmarks.views                        100  avgt   10   17,124 ±  0,818  us/op
```

Some points from those results:

- Of course nothing can beat the straightforward imperative implementation.
- The `fullTraverse` code (taken from your question) is actually quite efficient at tested data sizes. It maybe be best to use it.
- Out of lazy, functional implementations `iteratorsFold` is doing best and beats the `fullTraverse`.
- The overhead of doing such a simple task lazily is quite significant.
- `Stream`s are extremely inefficient, as expected.

Comment: Kolmar, thank you for detailed answer. How do you count Score? Is it Time?

Comment: I didn't expect such big overhead of lazy, can anybody advice any good reading about that?

Comment: @mulya Score is microseconds per operation (us/op as the last column states), it's what JMH outputs. As for overhead, here we are working on Strings, which enjoy many low level efficiency improvements by JVM. We introduce an abstraction `Iterator`/view/`Stream` over them, and the cost of that is high: creating temp object, functions calls that couldn't be inlined, etc.

Comment: @mulya Another issue is a lack of a good high-level function to traverse `Traversable[(Char, Char)]` to build `(String, String)`. `unzip` looks nice, but I think may end up traversing and filtering twice. `foldLeft` and approach in `iteratorsImperative` work well enough though. And `Stream`s are usually very ineffective, and in general shouldn't be used if `Iterator` or view is enough for the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can lazy filter your string using Streams like this:

```
def filterCharsLazy(s: String, chars: Set[Char], k: Int): String = {
  val s2: Stream[Char] = s.toStream
  s2.filter(a => !chars(a)).take(k).mkString
}
```

Interestingly `filterNot` does not seem to allow lazy execution, so I've replaced that with plain `filter`.

Tested with:

```
def time[R](block: => R): R = {
  val t0 = System.nanoTime()
  val result = block    // call-by-name
  val t1 = System.nanoTime()
  println("Elapsed time: " + (t1 - t0) + "ns")
  result
}
val str = "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf"*1000000
val chars = Set('a','s','b','c','e','g','h','j','k')

time { filterCharsLazy(str, chars, 10) }
```